# fsck.ext4 complaining that the device is in use. Can't find what exactly is using it

Tags: mount, storage-area-network, kubernetes, fsck, fibre-channel

Our setup is a 3-node RHEL 7.3 bare-metal Kubernetes cluster running on Docker.

We have a multipath FC SAN block device discovered on all three nodes. This device is used as a Kubernetes Persistent Volume with ext4 filesystem. The definition of this object follows as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: 2019-01-04T13:49:42Z
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  labels:
    ...
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: ...
    namespace: ...
    resourceVersion: ...
    uid: ...
  fc:
    fsType: ext4
    lun: 1
    targetWWNs:
    - ...04
    - ...15
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
status:
  phase: Bound
```

The pod using this volume crashed and upon restart started to complain about an inconsistency and requesting to run fsck.

```
Warning  FailedMount            1m (x13 over 26m)  kubelet, node2     MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "rtbm-prod-influxdb-pv" : fc: failed to mount fc volume /dev/dm-9 [ext4] to /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/fc/500
60e801232d404-lun-1, error 'fsck' found errors on device /dev/dm-9 but could not correct them: fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
k8s-san-0 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
k8s-san-0: Entry '675' in /data/_internal/monitor (262147) has an incorrect filetype (was 2, should be 1).


k8s-san-0: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

However we were unable to kick-off the fsck. We have undeployed the pod and fsck was still complaining with

```
# fsck.ext4 /dev/mapper/mpathb
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/mapper/mpathb is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

I tried to see what exactly was using the device:

```
# mount -l | grep -i mpathb
# lsof /dev/mapper/mpathb
# grep mpathb /proc/mounts
# fuser -m /dev/mapper/mpathb
```

But to all these tools the usage was invisible. What else could I check in order to find out what's holding my block device?

Comment: Are you using multipath storage drivers? Such as multipath scsi? Maybe you can stop the service with `service multipathd stop`. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/dm_multipath/mpio_setup

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks for the hint. In the meantime we've stopped docker and kubelet services which allowed us to fix the issue, but I was wondering if there's a more fine-grained approach that doesn't require a full node outage (we have multiple SAN devices on this node and stopping the multipath daemon would affect them all).